# how to hide linearlayout from java code?

Tags: android

I want to hide the linear layout so i used

```
LinearLayout mainLayout=(LinearLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
mainLayout.setVisibility(2);
```

but why is doesn't hide ??!!!

Comment: Using literal integers are highly not recommended,use LinearLayout.GONE or LinearLayout.VISIBLE instead.

Comment: why would it ? where did you get that value from ? just read the doc you'll find the proper constant to use !

Comment: why this question is "closed as not a real question"?

Comment: This closed question solved my problem. Why is this closed? How is it ambiguous, title says it all?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Use:

```
mainLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
```

Answer (score 21):

You can also set the visibility in your layout.xml if you want it hidden when your application first starts. 
`android:visibility="gone"` should do the trick. This way it is hidden from the very start when the layout is initialized by your app.

Answer (score 13):

Also you can use LinearLayout.**INVISIBLE**.

The difference is ([Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#INVISIBLE)):

> View.GONE - This view is invisible, and it **doesn't take any space** for
>   layout purposes.
>
> View.INVISIBLE This view is invisible, but it still **takes up space** for
>   layout purposes.

You can choose anyone based upon your design.

Answer (score 9):

The constant value used is wrong. It should be 8 for GONE. 4 for INVISIBLE and 0 for VISIBLE.

Check this [View description](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE) from the developer's site.

And this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644539/hiding-linear-layout-on-runtime-in-android).

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
mainLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.INVISIBLE);
```