# Hiding linear layout on runtime in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am having following layout

```
<merge>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_main"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_sub"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        />  
</merge>
```

What I want to do is to show/hide the ll_sub layout on runtime through `setVisibility()` but it is not working.

When I am setting `android:visibility="gone"` (also I had checked with `invisible`) from the xml of `ll_sub` then it is not displayed on the screen and this time when I use `setVisibility()` to show this layout on runtime, it is displayed but when I try to hide this layout once it is displayed then it is not hiding.

**EDIT**

I am trying to show/hide this linear layout on click of a button.

```
LinearLayout ll;
Button minimize;
int visibility=0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    ll=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll_sub);
    minimize=(Button)findViewById(R.id.minimize);
    minimize.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View view)
        {

            if(visibility==0)
            {
                visibility=2;
            }
            else
            {
                visibility=0;
            }
            ll.setVisibility(visibility);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You're not just forgetting to call invalidate?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like you're setting the wrong constants for changing [view visibility](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#VISIBLE).

```
GONE == 8
INVISIBLE == 4
VISIBLE == 0
```

However, you should never rely on the actual values that Android *happened* to designate to represent their constants.  Instead use the the values defined in the View class: `View.VISIBLE`, `View.INVISIBLE`, and `View.GONE`.

```
// snip...
if(visibility == View.VISIBLE)
{
    visibility = View.GONE;
}
else
{
    visibility = View.VISIBLE;
}
ll.setVisibility(visibility);
```

And don't forget to call `invalidate()` on the view :)

Comment: invalidate is incredibly important in a highly nested layout.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the Constants provided by View

```
View.INVISBLE, View.VISIBLE, View.GONE
```

and also invalidate your View

Comment: from one new user to another, its not about the reputation, its about spreading knowledge. Keep that in mind and upvotes will automatically come your way!

Comment: That comment was not about the "loss" of reputation. I don't care about that. I was just lucky to know something ;-)